# Broken Tortoise SVN repositories

Tags: tortoisesvn, repository

I'd some repositories in my old computer (which now it was already formatted) and I made the mistake of just copying them. Now I have a bunch of repositories and I'm not able to make any checkout. When I try I get the "no such revision" error with different numbers for each repository. In some cases (I can't figure out why) before the error it gets to checkout a few folders.

Is there any way I can recover the repositories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misunderstood the question. If the repositories are the server repositories, you can use `svnadmin dump`:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html

---

original answer:

Can you still 'export' the repo's?

If not, you can remove all of the .svn folders manually.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html

[image]

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, the .svn folders aren't in the client (each checkout) of the repository? I only have the repository folder.

Comment: The .svn folders are in the client. Do you have a copy of the repo from the server or the client?

Comment: The server.. Sorry the misunderstanding, didn't know the client was also called repository.

Comment: I can't use svnadmin dump. I'm doing: svnadmin dump D:\...\Repository > D:\...\dumpfile.dump and I get "svnadmin: invalid option"

Comment: strange - are you copying and pasting from this thread? if so, try typing it and see if you get the same issue - I have had problems like this before.

Comment: I typing all. Should I change the path of the server repository to /var/... (I'm working on Windows). If so, how?? Which is the starting path?

Comment: try running the command in the same directory as the repo is in

Comment: I was forgetting the quotes (because of the spaces in the path). It was done but I don't know where (it didn't allow any parameters for the .dump folder). How should I continue?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, after a commit i was unable to reach my local network drive stored SVN repository created with tortoise.

I got "No such revision 108".
It took me a while since I diffed an empty repository with my old one using WinMerge and started systematically delete files till tortoise gave me anything. First only an empty repository then i found the problem...

For some reason the first thing tortoise does in local repository is that it updates the current revision number within "db/current" file to the newest one than it allocates the new revision file and fills with the data. The problem comes if the process is interrupted and the "current" points to an invalid or not existing revision number.

---

So long story short:

### I was able to "recover" my repository by editing the "db/current" file given number to a valid revision (you can find a valid number under "revs/0/xxx" where xxx is the latest.

That's only true for locally created repositories.

To overcome this problem in the future I strongly suggest you to do the same as I've done:
instead of storing every project within one repository, create distinct repositories with simple trunk/branches/tags structure for each project, this way the corruption will isolated to one project.

Also note that by editing the current revision to a valid one means that you will probably lose data (the latest commit or update will be lost), I could find a way to restore that.
But didn't dig into cause I only lost a few hours of work.

Hope it helps many suffering of the same..

Comment: Two yrs later, this saved my life. Thank you! Note that if you are on windows, you have to remove the ".rev" extension on the revs/0/xxx.rev file that you want to revert to.